# Views Slideshow: specified number of images in random order?

Tags: views, media, javascript

I set up [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) so that it use the image field from a given content type. Total number of images in database under that field is 15.

What I want is a row of 6 random images on my home page that changes every x seconds. To achieve that I set the Views Slideshow pager option "Items per slide" to 6.

Now, everything works fine for the first and second slide, but the third slide has only 3 pictures (6 + 6 + 3 = 15), while I would like to have a full row of 6 pictures on every slide. If I set the Pager feature of the view itself (as I did before slideshow, using Grid format), the slideshow turns off (it has to be set to "Display all items"), so that's not the way to go about it.

Does anyone have any idea how to get that result?

Comment: This is a bit of a tricky one because view slideshow is loading all 15 images at run time and creating the slides as HTML then never going back to the server. What would be the expected result for the 3rd slide? Would you have the last 3 images and the 1st three images again? what would the 4th slide contain? images 3-9?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think 3-9 would be the simplest option. The other good one would be a "filling" set of random (not repeating) images from the database.

Comment: I should say I'd also tried jCarousel w/o VSS, but it lacks some effects and simply it's not the same goodness. 

Maybe it should be possible to determine the number of images by the view's (not VSS's) Pager function - the view engine would be responsible for randomizing/sorting them and VSS would only make the magic happen.